# GameScene method called from GameViewController: Thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewcontroller

I am quite new to Swift and I have the following issue.

This button in my GameViewController.swift:

```
var currentGame : GameScene!
currentGame = GameScene()


 @IBAction func restartGame(sender: UIButton) {
        currentGame.loadView()  
 }
```

This function in my GameScene.swift:

```
loadView(){
        ScoreLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 100))
        ScoreLabel.center = (self.view?.center)!
        ScoreLabel.text = "\(currentScore)"
        ScoreLabel.textColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        ScoreLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        ScoreLabel.font = UIFont(name: "GROBOLD", size: 80)

        HighScoreLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 7, y: -10, width: 300, height: 100))
        HighScoreLabel.text = "High Score: \(highScore)"
        HighScoreLabel.textColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        HighScoreLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        HighScoreLabel.font = UIFont(name: "GROBOLD", size: 30)
        self.view?.addSubview(ScoreLabel)
        self.view?.addSubview(HighScoreLabel)
}
```

At        ScoreLabel.center = (self.view?.center)!

Xcode tells me Thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

I have been googling this error and any related topics, without success.

The answers were unclear to me or unrelated.

Could someone please explain me what's wrong in my code ?

It seems my self.view doesn't exist and I dont' understand why.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I moved my ScoreLabel to my viewDidLoad method.

The view is certain to be instantiated in that method and therefore the nil error disappeared.

For a reason I cannot identify, the view hadn't loaded yet in my loadView method and that was what was causing the nil error.

Thank you for trying to help !

Answer (score 0):

```
ScoreLabel.center = (self.view?.center)!
```

Presumably `self.view` is nil at this point. You have a `!` at the end which assures Swift you know there is a view with a center. Since it's crashing, perhaps this assurance is based on an incorrect assumption.

A method named `loadView` should likely do something to load a view, right? The docs say to "assign the root view of that hierarchy to the view controller’s view property."

So this loadView method should include something like

```
super.loadView()
```

to get the view hierarchy ball rolling.

Comment: Xcode tells me I cannot assign to view property, it is  a get-only property... :/

Comment: So ensure you call `super.loadView` to get the view set, or rename your method to something like `addGameControls`. (I updated my answer.)

Comment: Renaming it will allow super's loadView to get called as per normal behavior, creating the view.

Comment: There exists no loadView method in the superclass... I created the loadView method, not Xcode by default ;) anyway, I fixed my issue, thx.